# java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException:throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException

Tags: java, junit, clone, hamcrest, spring5

I have upgraded java8 to 17 and spring4 to 5 , I am getting a test case failed.

java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @7960847b

```
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
```

here is my test case:

```
public class RestExceptionMappingHandlerTest {

private static final String EXPECTED_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = "testException";

private RestExceptionMappingHandler handler;

@Before
public void initHandler() {
    handler = new RestExceptionMappingHandler();
}

@Test
public void shouldHandleGenericException() {
    Exception testException = new Exception(EXPECTED_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE);

    final ResponseEntity<ClmErrorResponse> actualResponse = handler.handleGenericException(testException);

    assertErrorResponse(actualResponse, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, EXPECTED_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE);
}

private void assertErrorResponse(ResponseEntity<ClmErrorResponse> actualResponse, HttpStatus expectedStatus,
                                 String expectedMessage, Set<InputError> expectedErrors) {
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(actualResponse.getStatusCode(), is(expectedStatus));
    final ClmErrorResponse errorResponse = actualResponse.getBody();
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(errorResponse.getCode(), is(String.valueOf(expectedStatus.value())));
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(errorResponse.getMessage(), is(expectedMessage));
}

private void assertErrorResponse(ResponseEntity<ClmErrorResponse> actualResponse, HttpStatus expectedStatus,
                                 String expectedMessage) {
    assertErrorResponse(actualResponse, expectedStatus, expectedMessage, null);
}
```

Could someone please help here